# Does GnuPG store the revocation certificate in the keyring?

Tags: encryption, gnupg, certificates

I generated a revocation certificate in GnuPG.

1. If I repeat the procedure, will I get a *different* revocation certificate?
2. In case it doesn't, does the certificate gets stored in the GnuPG keyring?

Comment: No point in repeating the procedure. The revocation certificate relates to your public key, so you only create it once. The keyring stores your public keys. The revocation certificate once created stays off your keyring, until you decide to revoke your public key. Once it's imported to your keyring your public key is invalidated.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. In the meantime, I tried to repeat the procedure and obtained two different keys, except for the very first part of the string. I guess I can just erase one

Comment: @PaulBenson if you put it in an answer I will accept it